# iOS - connection to Bluetooth peripheral not working when shortcut option 'Show When Run' is disabled

Tags: ios, bluetooth, shortcut, siri

In my app the shortcut intent handler is scanning for Bluetooth devices and based of a given selection it connects to them devices and perform some actions.

Now as soon the option 'Show When Run' is set to disabled, the Bluetooth centralManager does no longer connect to any peripheral, device scanning is still working though and running the shortcut by Siri is working as well.
As a result, automation doesn't work and apparently I cannot use the shortcut as widget on lockscreen.

Does anyone know what else the 'Show When Run' option does, apart from raising a user notification after the shortcut completed?

Could this be a missing permission issue? I already added required keys on the info.plist for Bluetooth access and added Bluetooth background option on both app and shortcut targets.

Comment: After some research I noticed this seem to be a timing issue. The intent completion handler seem to terminate the whole intent. So the bluetooth handler has time to scan the peripherals but the actual connection process is terminated as well.

The option 'Show When Run' is preparing the IntentsUI - enough time for the bluetooth handler to complete connection and write process.

Answer (score 0):

Could solve my issue by implementing a check if write process to bluetooth peripheral completed, and only call the completion handler if that was either successful or failed.